# Jquery Dropdown on Click

Tags: jquery

So, I have a simple menu: when you click on ONE shows the ONE ITEMS, when you click on TWO shows the TWO ITEMS. The ONE and TWO have a toggle function, so they slides down and up on click, but when i toggle TWO without closing ONE, things get messy.

```
$(function() {

$('li.sub', '#navigation').each(function() {

var $li = $(this);
var $div = $('div.submenu', $li);
var top = $li.height();

$li.toggle(function() {

  $div.css('top', top).
  slideDown('slow');

},

function() {

  $div.
  slideUp('slow');

  });

 });

});
```

a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vGSWm/2/

Comment: Please don't include "thanks", "anyone?", or "smilies" in your question. They are useless noise.

Comment: What's the intended behavior? Could you describe exactly how you'd like it to behave when you click on two without first closing one?

Comment: toggle has been deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in 1.9. Might be good to find a solution that doesn't use it. Using a click handler is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this

```
$(function() {
    $('#navigation li.sub').click(function(e) {
        var el = $(this).find('.submenu');
        $('.submenu').not(el).slideUp(function(){
            el.slideToggle();
        });
    });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/vGSWm/6/)

**Update :**

```
$(function() {
    $('#navigation li.sub').click(function(e) {
        var el = $(this).find('.submenu');
        if(el.hasClass('open'))
        {
            el.slideUp(function(){
                el.removeClass('open');
            });
        }
        else
        {
            var opened = $('.submenu.open');
            if(opened.length)
            {
                opened.slideUp(function(){
                    opened.removeClass('open');
                    el.slideToggle(function(){
                        el.addClass('open');
                    });
                })
            }
            else
            {
                el.slideToggle(function(){
                    el.addClass('open');
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vGSWm/10/).

Comment: But why when I add a THREE element, doesn't work anymore? http://jsfiddle.net/vGSWm/7/

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, you need to programatically trigger the toggle on any of the list items that are already open.

The easiest way to do this is to add in code before you show the div for the menu that has just been clicked to hide all of the divs.

For example edit the function so it reads:

```
$li.toggle(function() {

  $('div.submenu:visible').parent('li.sub').click();

  $div.css('top', top).
  slideDown('slow');

},
```

This solution presumes that you may want to have more than two list items and will scale for any number. If you know that you will only ever have two list items you can call the list item directly.

Comment: This doesn't work. It correctly hides any open divs, but on the next toggle of a div that was closed this way, the toggle function will try to close the div again, doing nothing...

Comment: @SimonC Changed solution to manually trigger the toggle rather than just hiding the div. Well caught!