# Jquery slideUp callback function when initial selector includes child

Tags: jquery, slideup, jquery-callback

How can I add a callback function to the `slideUp()` function if the initial selector I am using includes `children()`?

```
$('.homebuttonbutton').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().children('.homebuttonaction').slideDown();
        $(this).children('.homebuttonlabel').addClass('whitebutton');
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().children('.homebuttonaction').slideUp(300, function() {
             $(this).children('.homebuttonlabel').removeClass('whitebutton');
        });
        //$(this).children('.homebuttonlabel').removeClass('whitebutton');
    });
```

So ideally, when hovered, the child `.homebuttonaction` slides down and has the `.whitebutton` class added, and then when un-hovered, the `.homebuttonaction` slides up and the `.whitebutton` class is removed.

I'm hoping to have the class removed AFTER the `slideUp` animation is finished, but I'm not sure how to 'select' it, as the initial selector is using `children` for the callback function.

There are going to be multiple `.homebuttonaction` classes, so I can't just use

```
$('.homebuttonaction').removeClass('.whitebutton');
```

because then it would apply to every one, right?  Does the callback function treat `$(this)` as the item being selected in the first place, or as the current selected item that was found through `children()`?

Thanks for the help, SO.

**EDIT**
Here is my fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kcxWc/ - as you can see, the class is not removed as it should be AFTER the slideUp effect is over.  I believe it is a selector issue...

Comment: You should not use `$(this)` inside `callback` instead, you can cache it outside like `var $this = $(this)` then use `$this` instead of `$(this)`. An answer similar to this is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058159/jquery-dropdown-on-click/15058628#15058628).

Comment: Is there any problem with the code? What does not happens as you expect?

Comment: @Andre the callback function, of removing the class, does not work.  I believe the selector is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` will refer to a `.homebuttonbutton` object in the mouseenter / mouseleave calbacks, and to a `.homebuttonlabel` object in the slideUp callback.

To refer the `.homebuttonbutton` inside the callback, you can seach the dom tree, or capture a reference to it in a closure.

Traversing the dom tree:

```
$(this).stop().children('.homebuttonaction').slideUp(300, function() {
    $(this).closest('.homebuttonbutton').children('.homebuttonlabel').removeClass('whitebutton');
});
```

Capturing in a closure:

```
var homeButton = $(this);
$(this).stop().children('.homebuttonaction').slideUp(300, function() {
    homeButton.children('.homebuttonlabel').removeClass('whitebutton');
});
```

Comment: please see my edit.  Your explanation is informative and appreciated, but I cannot seem to get it to work with either children or sibling, or closest.

Comment: sigh... nevermind.  It worked perfectly.  Very apreciated! - http://jsfiddle.net/kcxWc/1/

Comment: This seens to be working, with the `closest` example: http://jsfiddle.net/kcxWc/2/

Answer (score 1):

You don't always have to rely on the "this" keyword. Those functions are passed the event object, and you can find the "item selected" by the event.target property. For example.

```
$('.homebuttonbutton').hover(function(event) {
    var onlyTheButtonThatWasClicked = event.target;
});
```